# Get elements by class-name but not changing all elements with this class at click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the "key-selector" (e.g. "A","B" etc)color of the respectively clicked element. When I am clicking on a option block only the background color of the respectively block is changing like desired but the color of the "key-selector" is undesired changing in every block and not only of the clicked one, I do not understand why. Why is that not working and how can I implement this? (Look at my JS)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const option = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
  const keySelector = document.getElementsByClassName("key-selector");
  let i = true;
  const forward = document.getElementById("forward");

  Array.from(option).forEach(function(option) {
    option.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (i) {

        option.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(77, 55, 120)";
        option.style.opacity = "0.65";
        option.style.color = "white";

        Array.from(keySelector).forEach(function(keySelector) {
          keySelector.style.color = "white";

          forward.style.color = "white";
          forward.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(77, 55, 120)";
          forward.style.transition = "1s ease";
          i = false;
        });
      } else if (!i) {
        option.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(226, 226, 226)";
        i = true;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 4rem;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.options {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 313px;
  max-width: 750px;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 8rem;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  height: 418.75%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 21px 25px 22px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16.8px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.button:checked {
  color: red;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

.button:hover {
  /*background-color: rgb(116, 181, 218);*/
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  opacity: 0.65;
  color: white;
}

#backward:hover,
#forward:hover {
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  color: white;
}

.key-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #333;
}

.button:hover .key-selector {
  color: white;
}

.button-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 83px;
}

#backward {
  background-color: rgb(101, 93, 93);
  color: white;
}

#forward {
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="client.html">Mandant</a></li>
    <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="case.html">Anliegen</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="options">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>A</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">0</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>B</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">1</div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>C</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">2</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>D</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">3</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>E</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">4</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="button-bar">
    <div class="nav-inner" id="backward">
      < Zurück</div>
        <div class="nav-inner" id="forward"> Weiter ></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: To compare values, use `===` as in `if ((i === true)) {`. Same for the `false` comparison. Or *even better*: use `if (i) {` and `if (!i) {` because boolean values have the perfect datatype to feed directly into an `if`. Finally, you may notice that I also removed unneeded round braces. I will now vote to close this as "caused by a typo".

Comment: thank you, but it is still not working so no need to close

Comment: @PeterB Your comment is inconsistent. `if (i)` is equivalent to `if (i == true)` rather than `if (i === true)`, because it tests if `i` is *truthy*, not if it's exactly equal to `true`. So are you sure they should use strict equality?

Comment: @Barmar in the code the assignments to `i` are only `true` and `false`, and that is what I based my advice on. You are making up a different scenario. The truthy conversions will only occur of `i` is not a boolean, but it always is boolean. Also, I wasn't saying that the code is the same for random values of `i`, I was saying that booleans are perfect for use in if-statements.

Comment: @PeterB If those are the only assignments, then why is it necessary to use `===` instead of `==`? There won't be any type juggling that you need to prevent.

Comment: You know the answer to that question, and so do I. I'm just not going to waste my time "proving" it by explaining it to you. Feel free to share your deep knowledge with the world. Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop ``Array.from(keySelector).forEach(...)`changes the color of all the`key-selector` elements, not just the one related to the button that they clicked on.

It should just find the `.key-selector` element within the current button, and change that.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const option = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
  let i = true;
  const forward = document.getElementById("forward");

  Array.from(option).forEach(function(option) {
    option.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (i) {

        option.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(77, 55, 120)";
        option.style.opacity = "0.65";
        option.style.color = "white";
        let keySelector = option.querySelector(".key-selector");
        keySelector.style.color = "white";

        forward.style.color = "white";
        forward.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(77, 55, 120)";
        forward.style.transition = "1s ease";
        i = false;

      } else if (!i) {
        option.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(226, 226, 226)";
        i = true;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 4rem;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.options {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 313px;
  max-width: 750px;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 8rem;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  height: 418.75%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 21px 25px 22px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16.8px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.button:checked {
  color: red;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

.button:hover {
  /*background-color: rgb(116, 181, 218);*/
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  opacity: 0.65;
  color: white;
}

#backward:hover,
#forward:hover {
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  color: white;
}

.key-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #333;
}

.button:hover .key-selector {
  color: white;
}

.button-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 83px;
}

#backward {
  background-color: rgb(101, 93, 93);
  color: white;
}

#forward {
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="client.html">Mandant</a></li>
    <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="case.html">Anliegen</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="options">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>A</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">0</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>B</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">1</div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>C</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">2</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>D</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">3</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="key-selector">
          <span>E</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">4</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="button-bar">
    <div class="nav-inner" id="backward">
      < Zurück</div>
        <div class="nav-inner" id="forward"> Weiter ></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. But what is really confusing for me: why it is working for the blocks backgrounds color as it should and not like the way it is working regarding to the key-selectors (before you solved this problem)

Comment: Because those are operating on `option`, which is the button that they clicked on.

Comment: But the same principe for the key-selectors or not?

Comment: No, you had a loop that was changing the color of all of them, not just the one in the current option.

Comment: `Array.from(keySelector).forEach(...)` changes all the key-selectors.